# Deploying with docker push is slow because there are many images

Tags: deployment, docker

I'm trying to deploy via docker. I'm using the following workflow:

1. Build locally
2. Push my image to docker hub
3. On the server: pull the image
4. On the server: start the image

But docker push takes FOREVER. There are like 30 images, and it has to walk through each one and say "Image already exists". Is there any way to speed this up?

Alternatively, should I be using a different process to deploy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a local registry, we recently added a redis cache which has helped speed things up tremendously.  Details about how to do this are on the registry github page

https://github.com/docker/docker-registry

While pushing still takes time on new images, pulls are very fast, as all layers are in the redis cache.

Comment: What about checking for images that are already pushed? It takes ~2-3 seconds per image layer right now, so even if they are all already cached it takes forever.

Comment: This is instantaneous with our setup.  If you're storing to s3, redis is helpful.  I don't push a lot to dockerhub, so I can't speak to that.

Comment: Docker-registry is deprecated in favor of docker distribution. It supersedes the docker/docker-registry project with a new API design https://github.com/docker/distribution

Comment: It looks like the inmemory cache is the default option now, so redis doesn't make too much difference.

`docker exec -it registry cat /etc/docker/registry/config.yml`

storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: inmemory

Answer (score 14):

If you are pushing on AWS ECR, like I was, it may be that docker on your local needs to restart. See thread about AWS ECR slowness:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=222834

This may affect other platforms as well. It seems that around 1.12.1 on Mac, anyhow, there are some slowness issues that go away with a restart of Docker.

Comment: Had the same issue on my Mac 10.13.4 running Docker 18.06.1-ce-mac73 and pushing to ECR. Restarted docker, re-pushed, and worked like a charm.

Comment: @toringe How did you restart the docker at this point?

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: The Reboot is a very simple solution, but it has worked.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason why you are pushing more/large layers of your images on every deployment is that you have not optimized your Dockerfiles. Here is a nice intro [http://blog.tutum.co/2014/10/22/how-to-optimize-your-dockerfile/](https://web.archive.org/web/20170318002134/http://blog.tutum.co/2014/10/22/how-to-optimize-your-dockerfile/).

Comment: Anyway, for me, I use something like ansible to build the images on the server.

Comment: Link seems dead.